# AG-Grid change values of floating filters

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using AG-Grid. How can we change the value of floating filters by clicking a button present outside the grid? Look this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9NAfPeEu8GgJw7okqz77?p=preview&preview) example. It has a date picker column. How can I change value of date picker column and set it to 10-May-2020 on click on a button & refresh the data in grid ?

```
{
        headerName: "Date",
        field: "date",
        width: 145,
        filter: "agDateColumnFilter",
        filterParams: {
          comparator: (filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue) => {
            var dateAsString = cellValue;
            if (dateAsString == null) return -1;
            var dateParts = dateAsString.split("/");
            var cellDate = new Date(Number(dateParts[2]), Number(dateParts[1]) - 1, Number(dateParts[0]));
            if (filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getTime() == cellDate.getTime()) {
              return 0;
            }
            if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
              return 1;
            }
          },
          browserDatePicker: true
        },
        suppressMenu: true
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-floating-filters/#example-floating-filter) from docs.

You can define your filter function like below and call it onclick of button.

```
  filterDate() {
    var dateFilterComponent = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('date');
    dateFilterComponent.setModel({
      type: 'equals', //this is important
      dateFrom: '2020-05-10', // set the value here
    });
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged(); // this filters the grid 
  }
```